# Is it possible to remove a model by cid?

Tags: backbone.js, collections, model, coffeescript

I have a view called `Entry`.

```
class Movieseat.Views.Entry extends Backbone.View

  template: JST['movieseats/entry']
  className: 'movie-frame'

  initialize: ->
    @collection.on('change',  @render, this)
    @collection.on('remove',  @render, this)

  render: -> 
    $(@el).html(@template(entry: @collection))
    this

  events: -> 
    "click .remove":  "removeEntry"

  removeEntry: (e) ->  
    console.log @collection
```

This view creates a `Entries` template.

```
<div data-id="<%= @entry.get('id') %>">
    <p><%= @entry.get('title') %></p>
    <p><%= @entry.get('id') %></p>
    <p class="remove">Remove</p>
</div>
```

What I want to do is to remove a model from the collection (movieseats) and then rerender the template. If I click on a entry I fire the `console.log @collection` event. This logs the following,

```
Backbone.Model {cid: "c4", attributes: Object, collection: Movieseats, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}
```

How would I target the model's cid and then remove it from the collection?

**Update**

If I use this code,

```
removeEntry: (e) ->  
  thisid = $(e.currentTarget).closest('div').data('id')
  console.log @collection
  modelToRemove = @collection.findWhere({cid: thisid });
  @collection.remove(modelToRemove);
```

I get the following result in the console log.

```
Backbone.Model {cid: "c4", attributes: Object, collection: Movieseats, _changing: false, _previousAttributes: Object…}_changing: false_events: Object_pending: false_previousAttributes: Objectattributes: Objectchanged: Objectcid: "c4"collection: Movieseatsid: 531__proto__: Object
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

The problem seems to be this part,

```
modelToRemove = this.collection
```

Comment: Is `@collection` in your view really a collection? If it is a model then please call it `@model` to avoid all this confusion. Views hook up `@model` in the same way that they hook up `@collection` so you can call it what it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using this code (see [collection#remove](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-remove) method):

```
var modelToRemove = collection.findWhere({cid: "SOME_ID_HERE"});
collection.remove(modelToRemove);
```

See also [`findwhere`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-findWhere) docs.

#### Edit

From the output of the `console.log` method it appears that the `@collection` variable in your above code is not a true Backbone.Collection, but rather a model pointing to the collection. Thus, you should modify the above code to be:

```
trueCollection = @collection.get("collection") // or @collection.collection
modelToRemove = trueCollection.findWhere( cid: "SOME_ID_HERE" )
trueCollection.remove(modelToRemove)
```

Comment: I've updated my code, but getting a Uncaught TypeError. Could you check the question?

Comment: I think that curly braces should not be there in CoffeeScript

Comment: The error occurs before that though. It happens in the `collection.findWhere`.

Comment: That's weird. Is there a chance you could create a js-fiddle to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: `.findWhere( cid: "SOME_ID_HERE" )` What do you mean with "SOME_ID_HERE" ? Should I create a variable that stores the CID of the model model that's being clicked and then place it in the `.findWhere( cid: ... )' ? Like the `thisid` from the code above, but then cid?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma yes, I meant exactly this. But in your code you're populating the model's `id` in the template instead of `cid`, so make sure you're looking for the right property